# Flutter 3: Row layout not showing up in a Stepper

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, stepper

I am working on an onboarding screen where I want to have the onboarding in 3 steps, so using the [Stepper widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html). The Stepper widget is inside a Column as I want to have some text displayed over the Stepper first. But now when I am trying to use a Row inside the Step widget to display some data horizontally, it does not show up. But it works if I make it a Column.
What could be causing this and any possible fix?

**Flutter version: 3.3.8**

What I am trying:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 40),
              const Text('Hi there!', style: AppStyles.heading),
              const Text(
                'Let\'s get you started',
                style: AppStyles.subheading,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Stepper(
                type: StepperType.vertical,
                currentStep: _currentStep,
                physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                onStepTapped: (step) => onTapped(step),
                onStepContinue: onContinued,
                onStepCancel: onCancel,
                steps: [
                  Step(
                    title: const Text('Select a book'),
                    content: CustomButton(onPressed: () {}, text: 'Find Book'),
                  ),
                  Step(
                      title: const Text('Set your goal'),
                      content: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Pages',
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          CustomButton(onPressed: () {}, text: 'Set Goal'),
                        ],
                      )),
                  const Step(
                      title: Text('When you want to be reminded'),
                      content: TimePickerDialog(
                        initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 0),
                      ))
                ],
                controlsBuilder: (context, _) {
                  return Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => onContinued(),
                        child: const Text('Next'),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => onCancel(),
                        child: const Text('Back'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

CustomButton widget:

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final bool isOutlined;
  final bool isLoading;
  final bool isDisabled;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const CustomButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.text,
      this.isOutlined = false,
      this.isLoading = false,
      this.isDisabled = false,
      required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
          backgroundColor: isOutlined ? Colors.white : Pallete.primaryBlue,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 18),
          foregroundColor: isOutlined ? Pallete.primaryBlue : null,
          elevation: 4,
          side: isOutlined
              ? const BorderSide(color: Pallete.primaryBlue, width: 1.0)
              : null,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: isLoading ? false : true,
            child: Text(text,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
          ),
          Visibility(
              visible: isLoading,
              child: Loader(
                color: isOutlined ? Pallete.primaryBlue : Pallete.white,
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `TextField` and  `CustomButton` (while it has ElevatedButton) with `Expanded` widget.

```dart
Step(
    title: const Text('Set your goal'),
    content: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: const TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Pages',
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        Expanded(
            child: CustomButton(
                onPressed: () {}, text: 'Set Goal')),
      ],
    )),
```

Find more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)

Comment: That didn't work. Tried checking through widget inspector. Seems like the Row is not rendering or something. Can view other widgets in the tree in the Layout Explorer. But nothing comes up when selecting Row.

Comment: I just check the Stepper, it is possible on snippet too, btw there are some data `CustomButton` isnot available here. Can you simplify or include other widget. and try  `flutter clean`  and rebuilding the app

Comment: Added CustomButton definition in question. `flutter clean` and rebuild didn't work.

Comment: `ElevatedButton` button also have unconstrained width, wrap it with `Expanded`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
But could you explain a bit as to why the TextButton and ElevatedButton had unconstrained width in this case while inside the Row? I went through [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints) but could not get a clear picture

Comment: think like(story), row is providing infinite width,those two widget are trying to get infinite width and this is bot possible, we are using  expanded to get available space. check  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI